# Read data from database and display content in jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui, cakephp

I am new to CakePhp 2.0. I want to display information like about us in jquery ui dialog box. The content of the data is in the table aboutus. The table structure is 
aboutus-> fields (id, abtus) 
Is it possible to retrieve the data using ajax and then dynamically show the content in the jquery dialog box ? If so how? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you built the views, I mean the about us page is displaying without ajax?

Comment: Yes, I created a static page inside Pages/aboutus.ctp. However, i would like to implement it via database so I can use the same concept in other cases too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that in cakephp 2.0, but I satrted to make little things in ajax with this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ71psonQx0

Maybe it can help you too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will surely have a look at it

Comment: I finally decided to use static pages. However, as required I could load the file through jquery get() and then append the result to div and finally called the jquery dialog with the contents. If anyone wants clarification/code let me know will sure be glad to post it.